# MPMoviePlayerController behavior when moving to background / ResignActive

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to change playback behavior of `MPMoviePlayerController` when moving to background / ResignActive to be as other app's (e.g. youtube)

1. When moving to background pause when return to foreground
2. Don't pause when notification bar present

The problem is:

1. When moving to background / foreground (listening to app notification) `MPMoviePlayerController` ignore my request's to pause (`myMoviePlayer?.pause()`) when listening to `applicationWillResignActive` then pause is working but i want to pause only when returning from background (there is option for flag but i'm searching for elegant solution).
2. When user scroll down notification bar `MPMoviePlayerController` auto pause it and play it automatically when notification bar removed but i don't want to pause playback.